# Mechanize get content between "div's"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I am using the Mechanize gem.  How can I get content between two div tags?

```
"<div class='a'></div>content<div class='a'></div>"
```

The problem is, that content is between `<p>` tags.

```
<div>

  <div class='a'>Content1</div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div class='a'>Content2</div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You an use `Nokogiri` to parse the page after retrieving it:

```
m = Mechanize.new
result = m.get("http://google.com")

html = Nokogiri::HTML(result.body)
divs = html.xpath('//div').map { |div| div.content } # here you can do whatever is needed with the divs
                                                     # I've mapped their content into an array
```

Comment: This doesn't get content between (i.e. siblings to) the divs.

Comment: @MarkThomas how would you do that then?